# Deferred execution strategy in C++

Tags: return, deferred-execution

I have a callback implementation in which an unknown third party calls a function pointer in my code.

However, an issue in a lot languages is triggering code after a function returns. For instance, when a callback is called and I have to delete the calling object (and, in this case, re-initialize it), returning from the callback would cause an exception.

Assuming I cannot hook and that I do not own/cannot modify the code calling the callback, what is the best way to execute code after a function returns?

The only real way I can think of doing this is to set up some sort of state machine and have a worker thread check the state. However, the issue I foresee with this is that of a race condition, where a callback is called between the time the reset callback returns and the point the calling object is reset.

Is there any sort of functionality I'm not aware of, or would this be the most efficient way of achieving such a result?

Comment: What exactly is the "calling object"? Are you saying some code that's part of object X calls a function in your code and your function is supposed to delete object X? If so, *when*? Object X is clearly still in use when the function is called, so certainly not then.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - That's exactly what's happening.

Comment: Yeah, so you have a design problem. Your API doesn't give you any way to know when the object can be deleted safely. So either fix the API or accept that you will always have a race condition.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - That's what I figured :/ I can deal with the race condition. It's the ASIO (audio) SDK and needless to say it's pretty poorly put together. I could change the provided source/headers but then the third party drivers that implement the COM objects wouldn't work.

Comment: You'll have to fake it. Keep a table of the last time objects have been accessed and delete an object if it hasn't been accessed "in a while". If it doesn't particularly matter when you delete them, do a sweep on entry if you haven't done a sweep in, say, a minute. Otherwise, dispatch a thread to do a sweep however often you need.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Well the issue with that is that the callbacks are being called extremely quickly at random.

Comment: That's fine. On each callback, see how long it was since the last callback was called. If more than a minute, do a sweep. If the unpredictability is an issue, then have a thread do a sweep every so often, removing objects that haven't been accessed in a very long time. (Again, it's a hack. The API is broken, so what can you do if you can't fix it?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It requires c++11 or newer though. But this is how i would do it.
You can rewrite it to use function pointers instead so that it works on older c++ versions

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

#define CONCACT_IMPL(x , y) x##y
#define CONCAT(x, y) CONCACT_IMPL(x, y)
#define deffered(x) auto CONCAT(__deffered, __COUNTER__)  = Defer(x);

struct Defer {
    Defer(std::function<void(void)> pFunc) : func(pFunc) {};
    std::function<void(void)> func;
    virtual ~Defer(){
        func();
    }
};

int main() {

    deffered([] () {
        std::cout << "deffered" << std::endl;
    });

    std::cout << "now" << std::endl;
}
```

outputs -->

```
now
deffered
```

Comment: This doesn't fit the use-case in the OP specifically (I remember the problem I had a while back and it is simply not possible to do what I wanted). I'll accept this though since this is a pattern I've used before.